# How to unbox() a list for appropriate json formatting

Tags: r, jsonlite

Suppose I have the following list.  I would like to remove the outer layer.  I tried `jsonlite::unbox()`, but that function expects either an atomic vector or a 1-row `data.frame`.  `purrr::list_flatten()` works, but it doesn't give me much control over what is flattened.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

people <-
  list(
    list(
      person_1 = 
        list(
          first_name = 'ted',
          last_name = 'johnson',
          age = 45
        ),
      person_2 = 
        list(
          first_name = 'pam',
          last_name = 'wilson'
        )
    )
  )

toJSON(people, pretty = TRUE)
#> [
#>   {
#>     "person_1": {
#>       "first_name": ["ted"],
#>       "last_name": ["johnson"],
#>       "age": [45]
#>     },
#>     "person_2": {
#>       "first_name": ["pam"],
#>       "last_name": ["wilson"]
#>     }
#>   }
#> ]

unbox(people)
#> Error: Only atomic vectors of length 1 or data frames with 1 row can be unboxed.
```

My expected output is

```
#>   {
#>     "person_1": {
#>       "first_name": ["ted"],
#>       "last_name": ["johnson"],
#>       "age": [45]
#>     },
#>     "person_2": {
#>       "first_name": ["pam"],
#>       "last_name": ["wilson"]
#>     }
#>   }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `toJSON(unbox(fromJSON(toJSON(people))), pretty = TRUE)`?

Comment: It looks like you want `toJSON(people[[1]], pretty = TRUE)`, i.e. you want the json representing only the list that is the first element of `people`

Comment: FYI, `jsonlite::unbox` is to remove the brackets `[`/`]` around scalars (length-1 vectors) internally. It is normally used to wrap around _one thing_ in order to not `[`-bracket it. If you want the global effect, use `toJSON(.., auto_unbox=TRUE)`. If you do that, then you see that your output changes from `"first_name": ["ted"],` (etc) to `"first_name": "ted",`, but does not address the _outer_ `[`-bracketing you're trying to remove. Using AllanCameron's suggestion of `people[[1]]` does what you need for that.

Comment: One more BTW: `unbox` works on length-1 vectors or on `data.frame`s with 1 row. Even though a `list` might at times look similar to a frame, your data is not close enough to make a simple tweak to make it appear as such for `toJSON`. For instance, compare `toJSON(mtcars[1,])` with `toJSON(unbox(mtcars[1,]))`, all it's doing is _not_ wrapping in one layer of `[`-brackets. The `[1,]` concept for a `list` is not as simple nor global, but one might compare `people[[1]]` with `unbox(mtcars[1,])` for the same effect.